# Infragistics XamDataGrid issues with changing the selected item and focus

Tags: c#, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I have 3 XamDataGrids each with a different source, I want the different grids to act together so if the first grid is selected and the right arrow is pressed, the first grid should be deselected and the second grid should be focused and the first item in the second grid should be selected. This is working correctly, however, pressing the left arrow key does not seem to work. Focus is actually going to the right and no item is being selected. The logic used to determine the next grid is the same for both left and right clicks but for some reason only the left arrow key is causing issues.

View:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <dataPresenter:XamDataGrid Grid.Column="0" x:Name="Grid1" DataSource="{Binding Grid1Source}" PreviewKeyDown="Handle_PreviewKeyDown"/>
    <dataPresenter:XamDataGrid Grid.Column="1" x:Name="Grid2" DataSource="{Binding Grid2Source}" PreviewKeyDown="Handle_PreviewKeyDown"/>
    <dataPresenter:XamDataGrid Grid.Column="2" x:Name="Grid3" DataSource="{Binding Grid3Source}" PreviewKeyDown="Handle_PreviewKeyDown"/>

</Grid>
```

Code Behind:

```
    public TestView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        viewmodel = // Get ViewModel
        DataContext = viewmodel;

        viewmodel.Initialize();
    }

    private void Handle_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        var currentGrid = sender as XamDataGrid;
        switch (e.Key)
        {
            case Key.Left:
            case Key.Right:
                var grid = GetNextGrid(currentGrid, e);
                if (grid != null)
                {
                    ChangeGrid(currentGrid, grid);
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void ChangeGrid(XamDataGrid previousGrid, XamDataGrid nextGrid)
    {
        previousGrid.SelectedItems.Records.Clear();
        previousGrid.ActiveRecord = null;

        nextGrid.SelectedItems.Records.Clear();
        nextGrid.ActiveRecord = null;

        nextGrid.SelectedItems.Records.Add(nextGrid.Records[0]);
        nextGrid.SelectedDataItem = nextGrid.Records[0];

        nextGrid.Focus();
    }

    private XamDataGrid GetNextGrid(XamDataGrid currentGrid, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (currentGrid.Name)
        {
            case "Grid1":
                if (e.Key == Key.Left)
                {
                    return Grid3.Records.Count > 0 ? Grid3 : Grid2.Records.Count > 0 ? Grid2 : null;
                }
                else if (e.Key == Key.Right)
                {
                    return Grid2.Records.Count > 0 ? Grid2 : Grid3.Records.Count > 0 ? Grid3 : null;
                }
                break;
            case "Grid2":
                if (e.Key == Key.Left)
                {
                    return Grid1.Records.Count > 0 ? Grid1 : Grid3.Records.Count > 0 ? Grid3 : null;
                }
                else if (e.Key == Key.Right)
                {
                    return Grid3.Records.Count > 0 ? Grid3 : Grid1.Records.Count > 0 ? Grid1 : null;
                }
                break;
            case "Grid3":
                if (e.Key == Key.Left)
                {
                    return Grid2.Records.Count > 0 ? Grid2 : Grid1.Records.Count > 0 ? Grid1 : null;
                }
                else if (e.Key == Key.Right)
                {
                    return Grid1.Records.Count > 0 ? Grid1 : Grid2.Records.Count > 0 ? Grid2 : null;
                }
                break;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
public class TestViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region variables

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private ObservableCollection<string> grid1Source = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    private ObservableCollection<string> grid2Source = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    private ObservableCollection<string> grid3Source = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public ObservableCollection<string> Grid1Source
    {
        get => grid1Source;
        set
        {
            grid1Source = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Grid1Source));
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Grid2Source
    {
        get => grid2Source;
        set
        {
            grid2Source = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Grid2Source));
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Grid3Source
    {
        get => grid3Source;
        set
        {
            grid3Source = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Grid3Source));
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region INotify

    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyname)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
        }
    }

    # endregion

    public TestViewModel() 
    {
        Grid1Source = new ObservableCollection<string> { "Grid1 Test1", "Grid1 Test2", "Grid1 Test3", "Grid1 Test4", "Grid1 Test5" };
        Grid2Source = new ObservableCollection<string> { "Grid2 Test1", "Grid2 Test2", "Grid2 Test3", "Grid2 Test4" };
        Grid3Source = new ObservableCollection<string> { "Grid3 Test1", "Grid3 Test2", "Grid3 Test3" };
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Grid1Source));
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Grid2Source));
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Grid3Source));
    }
}
```

EDIT: Seems like the issue was not marking PreviewKeyDown event as handled

Comment: Perhaps, you are using the _custom control_ that caused problems in code from your previous question?

Comment: @Jackdaw in this case, the code given here is essentially all of it. I actually removed all unnecessary code for this example and I'm still seeing this issue